# Laravel project commit error

Tags: php, git, laravel-4

I committed a laravel project through github from my office PC. It worked nicely there, but when I tried to run the same project on my laptop, it showed the follow error. I cloned the project through github.

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException 
Open: E:\xampp\htdocs\design\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php

```
$others = $this->checkForAlternateVerbs($request);

    if (count($others) > 0)
    {
        return $this->getOtherMethodsRoute($request, $others);
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException;
}
```

Comment: `composer install` time!

Answer (score 1):

When you clone the github repo the Vendor folder doesn't come along with it. Remember the .gitignore file

Comment: fix that error..now this error happend..(edited questions).bdw thank u

Comment: run a composer update so It can update the new folders in the vendor directory

Answer (score 1):

user3666882 is right about the vendor's folder.

If you want to include the vendors file into your git repository, first run `composer update` (it will download all the necessary packages specified in the composer.json file). If you do not have composer installed, [check their documentation.](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows).

Hope it helps.

Edit: Since you've edited your question, the error you are now getting means that you don't have a specific route. Run `composer dump-autoload` and make sure that you are accessing an existing route and it is pointing to an existing controller method.

Comment: i did all these but failed. :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to also run `npm install` and `gulp` if you have any setup to pull in other depenencies. But the above answers are correct you need to run `composer update`